# SIFT between 1 image and dataset (2 images)

Tags: image-processing, opencv, c++, sift

I use SIFT, and I want to find the angle of inclination of an image compared to two reference images, in short:

I have 3 images :

Image x: input image

Two images 1 and 2, reference images that are very similar.

My goal is to find the angle of rotation between the image x and a combination between the two images 1 and 2. My problem is that I dont know how to combine the two images of the database to compare them with to the image x.

The purpose of the combination is to extract a vector Keypoints and Mat descriptor from the 2 keypoint vectors and the 2 Mat descriptors.

[image]

Comment: The obvious answer is to simply add them taking care of saturation. But this might complicate things depending on the nature of the two images. Is it possible to provide some more information about these two images? How about running SIFT twice and then getting the average between the two point estimates (?).

Comment: Sorry my diagram was not very clear i edit it now

Comment: The images are an image of a valve and  there is a QR code next the valve

Comment: ...I think that your previous diagram was fine. First combine the images, then run a single SIFT on them. The QR code's "features" are so stark they will simply persist. Except of course if you accidentally super impose them on top of some wall or ground texture that is like crumbled alimunium foil, that would throw the whole thing off pretty quickly.

Comment: The problem is i dont know how to combine the two images, they may be different in scale or one translated  compared to the other image.

Comment: Why do you want to combine these two images in the first place anyway? Are you trying to recognise a QR code within an image or do you want to recognise a QR code GIVEN that what you see is more likely to be a valve?

Comment: I know that if i use one image it's going to work, but i have to do it this way. because after i have to add more than 2 images. the QR code is only for valve identification but it's help me a lot with SIFT because of his pattern.

Comment: Ultimately, what are you trying to recover? The QR code? Something else?

Comment: The background (image without the valve)

Comment: That is odd...So do you expect that you will match up the two images, then subtract them....and get mostly the background? The reason I am asking what are you trying to do is because it might be possible to look at the problem differently and come up with a simpler or more manageable solution.

Comment: No, the two images are already a background, they are very similar, what i want is to use all the keypoints in both images the find this image(bothimages because the are similar) in video stream.